# Comparing variables, integer the same but types different (comparison operator)

Tags: python, types, comparison-operators

I've come across a weird test step that I can't seem to figure out. Basically in a test framework I'm testing for variables using a typical "should" and "is". The values returned are the same, but the step is still failing. After some tedious debugging, I realised that the failed steps also have different types despite the same values, like so:

```
Test 3.3:     Check value
HL Value test: HL_CodingCounter == 2
Normal Value test: sysConfigRWData.codingCounter == 2
Should: {
    'sysConfigRWData.codingCounter': 2
    'HL_CodingCounter': 2
}
Is: {
    'sysConfigRWData.codingCounter': 2
    'HL_CodingCounter': 2
}
is: 2, <class 'mySitePackage.datapoints.DataPoint_CodingCounter'>:
should: 2, <type 'int'>:

delta 
Should: HL_CodingCounter: 2 
Is: HL_CodingCounter: 2
Is: 2, <type 'int'>:
Should: 2, <type 'int'>:
```

Here you can see it is the `HL_CodingCounter` that is failing and not the other parameter.

So can it be when using the comparison operator (==) in Python, the `type` is also taken into consideration? And if so, how to I circumvent this so that only the actual value is considered?

Comment: The `==` operator is defined by the type. Most types do not compare equal if they are of different types. I don't know what you mean by "the actual value". That *is* what is being compared...

Comment: Just as I suspected. How can I compare on the value?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You *are* comparing by the value. It would help if you provide a [mcve] and not just some contextless output of some testing framework

Comment: In my case, i have two variables, each give "2", but their types are different: one is an integer, the other is a class.

Comment: How can a class be equal to an `int` object?  Note, I don't think your second object is a class object. I think it is an instance of a user-defined class. Again, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That's exactly my point. They are not equal, but the "output" for both is still 2. I find it weird behaviour. The "is" is using `mySitePackage.datapoints.DataPoint_CodingCounter` to get the value 2, and this is a class. The "should" gets its value from an excel spreadsheet, and the value there is an integer, 2.

Comment: You are incorrectly using terminology, and it's making this confusing. A class is a type of object, so `int` is a class object, `1` is an instance of the class object `int`. Again, it looks like there is some object which prints a string representation `2`, likely due to some attribute it possess. You probably want to compare the attribute to the integer 2. The *value* is some object from some library which reads excel spreadsheets. It is not `2`, which is an `int` object. It simply prints that character to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this due to changing a parameter name in my test, which had nothing to do with my Python test framework.